# adding refrence to MSComctlLib in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a class project in Visual studio using C#.
When I try to add reference to  MSComctlLib (Microsoft Windows Common Control 6.0 (SP6)) I get following message:

"a reference to Microsoft Windows Common Control 6.0 (SP6) can not be added"

I can add other versions of "Microsoft Windows Common Control" but not this one.

Does anyone know why.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727568/visual-studio-6-windows-common-controls-6-0-sp6-windows-7-64-bit Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @MikaelPuusaari .I will give it a try.

Comment: yep. It is resolved. @Mikael-Puusaari .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to re-register a type library to get rid of the issue. You might want to follow the directions in below link:

[Visual Studio 6 Windows Common Controls 6.0 (sp6) Windows 7, 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727568/visual-studio-6-windows-common-controls-6-0-sp6-windows-7-64-bit)

Comment: Thank you @RBT . I also used following link with FixIt exe file which resolved the issue.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/2703186